# Animate activity which is not part of your app

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation, android-activity

How can I apply closing transition on activity *which is not part of my app*. Say, I am opening *contacts app* for picking contacts, I apply slide up transition when opening contacts app but closing app applies default animation (slide left).

Is there any possibility of animating it on closing too?

Comment: were you able to fix your problem? i need solution too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume when you start activity of another app (in this example it is Contacts app) you use `overridePendingTransition()` in your activity for the animation, something like this :

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right_to_left, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

In `onResume()` method of your activity you can use `overridePendingTransition()` as well to animate activity (that is from Contacts app) from which you return:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Yes, tried it just now on Emulator. Didn't work for you?

Comment: Haven't tried, just wonder whether theoretically would it work.